# How to return a variable along with the promise from a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, promise

This is where I am stuck:

```
var verifyEmp = async function () {
    return 'Verified';
}


Employee.find(email, password)
.then((emp) => {
    console.log(emp);
    return verifyEmp();
})
.then((msg) => {
    console.log({ verificationMsg: msg });
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

As you can see, verifyEmp is a `promise` returning function(For demo purposes, I have kept this function as simple as possible). So, what I want to achieve is to be able to log { Emp: emp, verificationMsg: msg } in my second `then`. How do I pass emp variable in the second `then` while returning the `promise`.

I know this is conveniently achievable via async/await. I am just exploring how it can be done using traditional promises.

Comment: But you are still using `async` in your code, more so without `await`

Comment: You can just do `Promise.resolve(employeeObject)` in your first `.then`, and it will be available in your second `.then`.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava, yes I know. Please just assume that I don't want to use async/await in my other function. I want to know whether this thing is achievable using traditional promises or not.

Comment: @UtsavPatel, I have to get to the second then to resolve the VerifyEmp promise so that I can get that 'verified' msg. I can't resolve { emp: emp, verificatonMsg: msg } in the first then because I don't have verificationMsg yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use promises, you can nest a `then()` into the second one that resolves with the result of the first:

```js
const verifyEmp = async function () {
    return 'Verified';
}

const Employee = {
    async find() {
        return "An employee"
    }
}

Employee.find()
.then(emp => verifyEmp().then(msg => [emp, msg]))
.then(([emp, msg]) => {
    /* do something with amp and msg */
    console.log({emp: emp, verificationMsg: msg });
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return the `Promise` result from the `verifyEmp().then()` call (as `async` functions return a `Promise`) from the first `find().then` callback.

There you can pass *both* the result of the `verifyEmp()` call and also the `emp` object from the current scope wrapped in another object to the next `then` in the chain.

The `Promise` from the `verifyEmp().then()` gets automatically unwrapped in the next `then` callback in the chain:

```js
var verifyEmp = async function () {
    return 'Verified';
}

const Employee = {
  find: async function(email, password){
    return {email, password, "id":123};
  }
}

Employee.find("test@abc.com", "test")
.then((emp) => {
    //This promise woud get unwrapped in the next .then callback
    return verifyEmp()
           .then((msg) => ({emp,msg}));
})
.then((msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test it. Use an async iife or something of sort, if you hate anti-patterns. This solution will work regarless of verifyEmp returning a promise or not.

```
var verifyEmp = async function () {
    return 'Verified';
}


Employee.find(email, password)
.then((emp) => {
    console.log(emp);
    return (async function(){return verifyEmp()})().then((ver)=>[emp,ver]);
})
.then((msg) => {
    console.log({ verificationMsg: msg });
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: This makes no sense.  First off, you will know whether `verifyEmp()` returns a promise or not.  If you don't, then something else is wrong.  If you really want to wrap the return value of `verifyEmp()` in a promise, then just do this `Promise.resolve(verifyEmp()).then(ver => [emp,ver])`.  There's no reason for the extra `async` function.

Comment: It's not about typing savings, it's about writing code that is declarative and is obvious what/why it's written that way.  I say again, if you don't know what something returns, that's a serious problem.  If you actually are trying to use a function that sometimes returns a promise and sometimes returns a value, then throw that library away as that's a broken interface or fix the code.  A sometimes asynchronous interface should always return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Just return json object instead of string.

```
var verifyEmp = async function () {
    return 'Verified';
}


Employee.find(email, password)
.then((emp) => {
    console.log(emp);
    return {emp:emp, msg:verifyEmp()};
})
.then((res) => {
    console.log({ Emp: res.emp, verificationMsg: res.msg });
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```